# Firebase: displayName is null when signing in with signInWithCredential

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm singing in with Google, prompting the user for Google account email and password:

```
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const userCredentials = await signInWithCredential(
    auth,
    GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, token)
  );
console.log(userCredentials.user)
```

I'm getting back the user object successfully, with `email`, `photoURL`, `uid`, etc., however `displayName` is null. Is this an error or the expected result? I tried creating a new Gmail account, with name and even a nickname, yet `displayName` is still null. How can I get the `displayName`?

Comment: Hi does my posted answer helped you, if so acknowledge it if not then we can dive further.

Comment: Initially I was receiving the correct name and now every call I make returns null. I can't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`displayName`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.User#displayname) property of `User` is null by default. It depends on the User whether he/she has set the displayName at the time of creation or updating it later. But by default it is `null`.

If you want to update the displayName at place you can do that with [**`updateProfile`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) method as follows:

```
import { getAuth, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth(app);
const user = auth.currentUser;

await updateProfile(user, {
  displayName: "John Doe"
});

console.log(user.displayName);
```

If you are sure that displayName is there for your google account but not showing in the user.displayName then you need to check the token you are passing `null` to the idToken of [**`GoogleAuthProvider.credential()`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.googleauthprovider.md#googleauthprovidercredential) method make sure you also pass the valid idToken.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, what do you mean by "if you are sure that displayName is there for your google account" ? Is it null by default or sometimes not? Thanks

Comment: @sir-haver It is null by default but when set it will not null.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to "hack" a bit the issue about not getting `displayName` from `signInWithCredential`. Apparently and as it has been said before, `displayName` is always null. But if you sign in using `google_sign_in` lib and inspect `GoogleSignInAccount` object, you will see you will have that display name. Then, you can sign in to Firebase using the Google Sign In credentials you used before.
Here it is the code I used:

```
    try {
      GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
      GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleSignInAccount == null) {
        print('error getting google sign in account');
        return;
      }

      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount!.authentication;
      AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken, accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);

      var result = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential));
      user = result.user;
      displayName = googleSignInAccount.displayName;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

In `user` var you will have all user related variables coming from `firebase` authentication such as `uid`, and from `googleSignInAccount` you can get the display name.
I hope this can help someone!